# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 File Ordering

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to change the ordering of files in the solution explorer?  The reason I need to change this is that I have one file being run before the other and this file requires the 2nd one to have run first, so I am getting a "Invalid object name" error.

Comment: Do you mean the build or execution order?  Solution explorer is just for display.

Comment: I believe that's not the reason for your problem...

Comment: Execution order. So say if each file in a folder is being read one by one. What is shown in the Solution Explorer isn't going to be the order they are read in?

Comment: The display in Solution Explorer has nothing to do with build or execution order.  C# files are not run, they are compiled (as a whole).  You'll need to give more information about your solution and project structure and what exactly you're trying to accomplish before your questions about this can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the build order. To do this, `right click on the solution` in solution explorer and `click on properties`. Make sure you are under `start-up projects` and select the `Multiple start-up projects` radio button. You can then change the order on the right with the two arrows.

As others have said, I'm not so sure this is what you need to do...